# Access template options in module's construct method

Tags: javascript, apostrophe-cms, nunjucks

In [Apostrophe](https://apostrophecms.org/), I have a custom module where I would like to pass an option from the Nunjucks `apos.area` call to the construct method of the widget itself. Concretely, I want to adjust the output of `getWidgetWrapperClasses` based on the options passed to the module in the template. Is this possible?

Here's an example of what I would like to achieve:

`lib/modules/example-widgets/index.js`

```
module.exports = {
    extend: "apostrophe-widgets",
    label: "Example widget",
    construct: function(self, options) {
        self.getWidgetWrapperClasses = function(widget) {
            // templateOptions would be the options object as defined
            // in home.html below
            return ["column", "column-" + templateOptions.width];
        };
    }
};
```

`lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/views/pages/home.html`

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="widgets">

        {{ apos.area(data.page, "example", {
            widgets: {
                "example": {
                    width: "half"
                }
            }
        }) }}

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by not using the `getWidgetWrapperClasses` method, but instead extending the widget wrapper template and overriding a Nunjucks block in there. This is in fact a documented approach if you look in `lib/modules/apostrophe-areas/views/widgetBase.html` in Apostrophe's code.

I changed `lib/modules/example-widgets/index.js` like this:

```
module.exports = {
    extend: "apostrophe-widgets",
    label: "Example widget",
    wrapperTemplate: "wrapper",
    construct: function(self, options) {
        // Do something
    }
};
```

Then, I added a `lib/modules/example-widgets/views/wrapper.html` file. In that file, you can simply override the `extraWrapperClasses` block to add the classes you want, all the while having access to the template options through `data.options`.

```
{% extends "apostrophe-areas:widget.html" %}

{% block extraWrapperClasses %}column column-{{ data.options.width }}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Good solution. `construct` is called when the entire module is being constructed, not an individual widget, so it would never see the options passed to `apos.area` for a particular widget. `getWidgetWrapperClasses` potentially could, but we didn't think of that, so for now it only takes one argument; feel free to open a ticket asking for `options` to be the second argument.